# How to call inputs from main function in nested function

Tags: matlab

```
function x = Fun(y) 
  x = B(y) - 8;

  function z = B(x)
    z = Fun2(y,x) + 16;
  end
end
```

I want to use the input "y" in a function that runs inside the nested function. The problem is that I get undefined "y" error for the nested function.

Thanks!

**EDIT***

I updated the cuestion with a very similar problem that throws the same error.

```
function x = Fun(a,b)

  x = Fun3 (@Fun2)

 function y = Fun2(c) 
   y = Fun3(a,b) - 10;

end
end
```

Fun 3 is defined in another file, I don't think that it is the cause of the problem. I suspect the error comes from not being possible to pass arguments "a", "b" in the third function (Fun3) inside the second function (Fun2) whithout having them as arguments in Fun2. Any hint?

Comment: lol this is funny your code works fine on my computer. are you sure you are calling this code from command line `>> Fun(2) ans =10`

Comment: Did you save the file containing the above code as `Fun.m`?

Comment: @user2794659: It is a good idea to post a comment when you update the question with new information.

Comment: Is `Fun2` stored in a seperate file? Can you post its code? What is your Matlab version?

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to enter another function (Fun2) that is what is causing the problem. Yes Deve, it is a separate file and my version of matlab is R2010a. Thanks.

Comment: The example works in 2012b. But what is the expected outcome? Is the recursion intended?

Comment: Thanks Deve! Yes, even if I write the second function as a sub-function the error is still there. It seems that I cannot access to the value of "y" (inputed in the first function) in the second function.